# How to login ssh from windows host to Linux guest in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I have windows as Host for my virtualbox and `Ubuntu` as as Guest. How can I login from ssh command to my guest machine?

Comment: Please ask non-programming questions on [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Ok thank you, I will from next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Login ssh first install openSSH in your ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

then from virtualbox, go to setting->Network->Adapter 1->port Forwarding there will open one port forwarding box, click on `+` sign.
Give the name as you wish, protocol `TCP`, HOST IP `127.0.0.1` HOST port `2222` Guest IP `10.0.2.15` (what ever it is in guest ip, check by `ifconfig` command in ubuntu terminal) and Guest Port `22`

you can use **putty** or tools in windows to connect.

Comment: what should be network Adapter?

Comment: you have to select `NAT`